# Google Cloud setting up an organization without the original user

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My company has created a Google Cloud Provider account 2 years ago. The person that set it up is no longer with the company. We don't have access to his account or have any information. I am currently marked as an owner but everything I try says I need to have `super admin` role. My goal is to tie this into our Azure AD but my digging says that I need that role to do anything. I can't contact support without paying and I can't pay for support because I am not the administrator. I have access to that user's email but it's asking me for their phone number. How do I get access to our account?? I can't create a new one because our domain is tied to this current one and we have 2 years worth of work in here.

I see errors like:

1. You do not have an Organization resource.
2. Your current account is not an administrator of an organization on Google Cloud.
3. Your current account doesn’t have the permissions to perform this task. Log into the Cloud Console using your Cloud Identity super administrator account.

Comment: Fortunately, Google Cloud security is very good. For you, that means you must engage Google Cloud support to take over the account. Note: the `super admin` role is a Google Workspace role so that means you also have a Workspace account to take over as well unless it is a Google Cloud Identity Platform account. Check if you have access here: https://console.cloud.google.com/customer-identity/providers

Comment: I do have access there.

Comment: I need more details. You mention you are an `Owner`. An owner of what? (one project, multiple projects, etc.). Google does have a recovery link that you can try: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/find-billing-account-administrator#no-billing-access

Comment: Based on the details in your question and your response, I recommend that you engage someone that knows Google Cloud IAM, organizations, and billing well. Taking over an account will require business documentation, so start organizing that as well. You will need to prove that you have the authority.

Comment: I have access to two projects. my personal test project and my companies project. I want to set up GCP to use my companies Azure AD for it's users instead of manually controlling users. So when an employee tries to login to GCP, that it uses their AD credentials instead. Under the IAM, I have a role of `owner` and `organization admin`.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will try that recovery method and see where it takes me

Comment: Those details do not matter (what you plan to do). Personal projects also do not matter. The details I am asking for are regarding the Google Cloud Organization that you are trying to gain control of.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transfer the ownership of the Organization as mentioned by @John Hanley. Contact support to have them assist you with the process. For your reference here is a documentation about migration in GCP that can be helpful with your use case. [1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration

Comment: The only way I can see to contact support is to pay for it which I can't do because I am not the admin.